# Easymotion remapping not working (does nothing)

Tags: key-bindings

Here's my section for `Easymotion` in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:EasyMotion_do_mapping = 0
let g:EasyMotion_smartcase = 1
let g:EasyMotion_startofline = 0

nnoremap fw <Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)
nnoremap fW <Plug>(easymotion-bd-W)
nnoremap fe <Plug>(easymotion-bd-e)
nnoremap fE <Plug>(easymotion-bd-E)
nnoremap fb <Plug>(easymotion-bd-b)
nnoremap fB <Plug>(easymotion-bd-B)
nnoremap ff{char} <Plug>(easymotion-s)
nnoremap ft{char} <Plug>(easymotion-bd-t)
nnoremap F <Plug>(easymotion-repeat)
nnoremap <C-f> <Plug>(easymotion-next)
nnoremap <C-F> <Plug>(easymotion-prev)
nnoremap fj <Plug>(easymotion-sol-j)
nnoremap fk <Plug>(easymotion-sol-k)
```

Expected behavior: like the default bindings but replacing `<Leader><Leader>` with `f`.

Reality: pressing `ff` (and the other bindings) doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried this with `nnoremap` and `map` but neither works. How should I fix this mapping?

Comment: Mappings to `<Plug>` entries need to be recursive, since the `<Plug>` entries themselves are mappings as well.
Also, you don't really add `{char}` explicitly to your mapping. But I think there's more than that to your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using `map` instead of `nnoremap` and removing the `{char}`s. The following code now works:

```
map fw <Plug>(easymotion-w)
map fW <Plug>(easymotion-W)
map fe <Plug>(easymotion-bd-e)
map fE <Plug>(easymotion-bd-E)
map fb <Plug>(easymotion-b)
map fB <Plug>(easymotion-B)
map ff <Plug>(easymotion-s)
map ft <Plug>(easymotion-bd-t)
map F <Plug>(easymotion-repeat)
map <C-f> <Plug>(easymotion-next)
map <C-F> <Plug>(easymotion-prev)
map fj <Plug>(easymotion-sol-j)
map fk <Plug>(easymotion-sol-k)
```